# WP get specific ID and echo

Tags: html, css, arrays, wordpress

I managed to get all the ID's from this post but got confused how to get just 2 specific id's to output 2 specific terms.

Basically I have 2 terms (available and not available), let say available = 1, not available = 2; I know I have to array them as I want to style these ID's differently.

```
<?php
  /* Property Status. For example: For Sale, For Rent */
  $status_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,"property-status" );
  if(!empty($status_terms)){
      foreach($status_terms as $st_trm){
          echo $st_trm->name;
  break;
  }
    }else{
      echo '&nbsp;';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: that code is inside `the loop` made for a single post. so you need to change your post loop.

Comment: Yeah I know I want to keep it that way but still target 2 specific ID's. Can't I just use } else { then array the IDs that I want to echo?

Answer (score 0):

in that case..

use

```
if( ($post->ID ==1)||($post->ID==2)){
 $status_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,"property-status" );
  if(!empty($status_terms)){
      foreach($status_terms as $st_trm){
          echo $st_trm->name;
  break;
  }
    }else{
      echo '&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this may sound silly but to echo it, is just like echo $post->ID == 1? Need to put it inside a span or div to style it.

Comment: this code already echoing your normal output but limited to 2 post id.. ` echo $post->ID == 1` will return a boolean value

Comment: Oh right, is there a way to style ID 1&2 differently? That's why I asked if I can array them and echo separately.

Comment: style them by attaching a class to the div when echo them.. `echo '<span class="item_id_' . $post->ID . '">'.$post->name .'</span>';`